# A string variable becomes a tuple

Tags: python

Update: Fixed the problem. I have commas behind my strings because I copied an pasted them over a dictionary.

I have a config.py file with some string variables inside like

```
MAIL_SERVER='email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
```

However, when I import it into another class, the variable becomes a tuple.

```
type(config.MAIL_SERVER) # result <type 'tuple'>
```

Can someone share some knowledge on this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a trailing comma after the string?

Comment: what if you print config.MAIL_SERVER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are having `,` after the string. Removal of that should fix the issue.

Comment: It does but a comment is not a real answer ;)

Comment: @d6bels, I was referring more to the fact the OP has edited the top of their post and put *Update: Fixed the problem. I have commas behind my strings because I copied an pasted them over a dictionary.*. Also it is a typographical error so should simply be closed

Comment: Thanks for the help. Hope @PadraicCunningham won't feel hurt.

Comment: @Shang, I will try not to ;)